# How to resolve: "Hostname/IP does not match certificate's altnames" when fetching from subdomain?

Tags: rest, nginx, ssl, vercel, lets-encrypt

I have two apps, one hosted on DigitalOcean under api.exampledomain.com and one hosted on Vercel under exampledomain.com
I am trying to trigger a webhook that is on my main domain from my subdomain. But I get the following error:

*request to https://exampledomain.com/api/revalidate failed, reason: Hostname/IP does not match certificate's altnames: Host: exampledomain.com. is not in the cert's altnames: DNS:api.exampledomain.com*

When I test the trigger on my subdomain(api.exampledomain.com) it works with sites like these [webhook.site](https://webhook.site). And when I try using the real webhook(on exampledomain.com) using Postman it works, this on localhost of course. So the error only happens when I call the webhook(on exampledomain.com) from the subdomain(api.exampledomain.com).

The certificates on api.exampledomain.com are created by Let's Encrypt, and proxied using NGINX.

- I tried setting CORS headers to '*', but that did not fix it.

Comment: Try both in your certificates both `api.exampledomain.com` + `*.exampledomain.com`

Comment: @J-JacquesM I only have access to change the certificate of api.exampledomain.com would that suffice?

Comment: You need to request/generate a new certificates with `altnames: api.exampledomain.com` present inside the new certificates, then yes you change it